# How can I make a foreign key only able to reference a subset of rows in the target table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a table with a primary key (lets call it "person"), and another table that references it (lets call it "grade", as in student grades).

Table "grade" has field "grade.personid", which is a foreign key to "person.personid". Lets say "person" has field "person.type" as well (varchar with possible values of "student" or "teacher" for simplicity), and only students have grades.

How do I make the database reject any inserts/updates that put the "personid" of a non-student (i.e. teacher) in the "grade.personid" field.

I'm currently working with Sql Server 2008, but would be interested in answers for other platforms too.

```
                 [ grade  ]
[ person ]       [--------]
[--------]       [gradeid ]
[personid] <-FK- [personid]
[type    ]       [data    ]
[name    ]
```

*p.s. I'm aware of constraints on schema bound views but don't really like them because they break whenever anyone modifies the tables they rely on.*

Comment: Not a great analogy--a person can be both a student and teacher, assuming post-secondary, at the same institution.  Is the relationship you're trying to constrain actually mutually exclusive?

Comment: fnuh, well at a uni perhaps. think primary school, it's probably less likely there :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of SQL Server desired logic can be implemented by defining `INSTEAD OF` trigger. For Mysql server, for instance, you will need to define `BEFORE` trigger.

**UPDATE**. Example of trigger(SQL server)

```
CREATE TRIGGER ON [grades] INSTEAD INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS(   
   SELECT 1 FROM [person] WHERE personid = inserted.person_id AND person.type  = 'student'
   )
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('Invalid person type', 10, 1);
   END;

   INSERT INTO [grades] SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

For mysql, it should be `CREATE TRIGGER ... BEFORE INSERT`. Also, mysql doesn't have an analogue of `RAISEERROR`, so you will need to generate an error to prevent inserting. Usually, I use `INSERT INTO not_existing_table(id) VALUES(1,2)` to get a runtime error in a trigger body.

Comment: Could you give a fuller example? I'm not sure how that would work. Thanks for the answer, I hadn't thought of triggers!

Comment: I added an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: from within a trigger the best way to error out is to use RAISERROR (like you do) but also follow that up with a ROLLBACK then a RETURN command. see http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#triggercontext

Comment: That's a fab answer. thanks a1ex07. I think this will be much more robust than the schema bound view option and sufficiently discoverable.

Comment: @Tim Remember this only covers one side of the FK relationship. Also this approach can fail if you use snapshot isolation.

Comment: Good point, so you could add a grade for a student, and then change them to become a teacher.

Comment: I've never heard of snapshot isolation! (I'm not a sql server dba and don't particularly intend to become one).

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
                 [ grade  ]
[ person ]       [--------]
[--------]       [gradeid ]
[personid] <-FK- [personid]
[type    ] <-FK- [type    ]
[name    ]       [data    ]
```

put a single FK on personid+type and add a check constraint on grade.type to only allow student type.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea. In my opinion, denormalization is useful for reports, but not for storing original data.

Comment: With the CHECK constraint, how would you have a teacher/role that shouldn't be allowed a supporting child record.

Comment: That indeed would work in my contrived example, and is quite imaginative, but I think it makes me cringe more than other possibilities (including do nothing or handle it in the application layer). Worth a +1 as an answer though, so thanks!

Comment: OMG Ponies, would a teacher have a grade?  the most realistic way for production code is the constraint on schema bound view  as the OP mentions, or a trigger as @a1ex07 states. I was just trying to come up with a way to use a FK

Answer (score 0):

And for the record, here's an anonymized version of what worked for me:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigRestrictGradeToStudents
ON dbo.grade
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT person.personid
    FROM person
        INNER JOIN inserted ON person.personid = inserted.personid
    WHERE (type = 'student')        
)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION --prevent the insert/update from proceeding
    RAISERROR ('Only students may have grade records', 11, 1)
END
```

Severity set to 11 to make it show in the error message before "The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted."

See also [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) (sic)